# Sound proofing underneath the drumset

Tags: drums, noise

I live on the 3rd floor of my apartment and people downstairs are just about to lose it cos of me practicing my "L R Kick" triplets.

**I want to know if there is an intelligent, makeshift way to soundproof the floor to minimise the noise of the Kick drum.**

*PS : I already have mute pads on the all the heads.*

I was thinking what if I put 2 yoga mats underneath it? would that be any good?

Comment: http://music.stackexchange.com/questions/9542/electronic-drums-in-apartment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do they have problems with the snare, or is it really just the kick? I'd be willing to bet that half the problem is from the pedal stomping rather than the actual kick drum sound. Actually, I just realized you said you already have mute pads on, so it's probably a little more than just half the problem. They probably can't really hear much of the actual drum kick sound, they just experience shake, shake, shake.
I see people suggesting electronic drum kits; however I feel these will do you no good as most good ones use real kick pedal apparatus with a mallot that strikes a stopper pad/sensor. Also, an electronic drum kit is essentially nothing more than mute pads with sensors, so if you have a problem now an electric kit won't solve it.

If you have high enough ceilings you could do a quick and dirty drum riser by placing masonry cement bricks next to each other in maybe a 9 brick x 9 brick pattern. Maybe more, idk, but if you look it up the VERY best thing for blocking sound is cement brick. Just as good as noise cancelling foam, if not better. Also, I believe, better than attempts to "float" the floor.

While it's not floating, it will probably help with the direct transfer of the vibration of using the pedal as well but if you could suspend yourself with cables that'd be ideal ;).

Of course, I don't know how crazy you are willing to get, but you could conceivably enclose the entire bass drum and kick pedal apparatus in a sound-proof enclosure, with some sort of access panel/door that lets your leg in so you can press the pedal.

However, since I don't really think the problem is in the sound transfer so much as the vibrations caused when playing, your best bet would be the cinderblock riser. If that's too heavy for your floor, then your gonna have to either move or drive your neighbors to move out. :) Hope this helps.

Comment: Yep, absolutely. Okay, the VERY BEST thing for soundproofing is MASS and out of readily available construction materials, cement cinderblocks are the best mix of price, availability and ease of installation. Plus you're not committed much if it doesn't work out for ya. :)

Comment: Plus, he asked for "an intelligent, makeshift way" to do it... you just told him "get mass" whereas I told him a possible way to go about doing that.

Comment: Oh, I don't care, I was just saying... but why couldn't you build a makeshift riser from cinderblocks? You said that there's no ready, makeshift way except to reiterate what you said, but all you said was that mass was probably "out of the question unless you want a new concrete floor..."

Comment: I could see using a rubber pad underneath a cinderblock riser... the riser would absorb the vibrations from the pedal and the rubber pad would damp the worst of it.  Wouldn't do much at all from a 'soundproofing' perspective but it would stop the annoying foot-pedal-action-through-the-ceiling, so when combined with an electronic drumset I'd imagine it to be quite effective.

Answer (score 2):

It is the vibration that bothers. Electronic drums will not help. If the raiser is not an option, consider reducing muffling the vibration between the pedals and the floor. I had this problem even though I was using a practice pad-set. My solution was to get a set of excersice mats (http://www.greatmats.com/products/home-sport-play.php?kmas=1&kmca=Shopping+PLA&kmag=Exercise:+Sport+&+Play+Mats+2x2+Ft+x+7/8+inch&kmkw=%27%27excercise+mats%27%27&kmmt=p&gclid=CjwKEAiAiZK1BRD509nPsYiUk2YSJAAMoAwCKuVZt0iivm-enwwoduv_h9CQVoE--dq--hnOJpvvkxoCAqjw_wcB), a cardboard, and a ribbed area rug (http://www.americanfloormats.com/ribbed-entrance-mats/) underneath the set and that stopped the vibrations from the double pedal. I had hardwood floors so I put the excersice pads first. Then to cardboard box folded flat and on top of that, the rug on top of that. That worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Facing those problems, I'd be looking at buying an electronic set of drums, or at least a kick and snare to start with. Another advantage is that they can be set up in another part of the flat, maybe bathroom, which is probably over your neighbour's bathroom, not used too often.The mats would then be quite useful, but most of the noise will be in your headphones. Cheap? Not necessarily, but cheap-er than moving or bust-ups ! And the kit can supplement your original when doing gigs.

Comment: I second this answer.  I also live in an apartment.  I dared only use a practice pad kit (4 pads up, and a small pad where my double kick goes).  I was able to use it for about a month, but eventually the neighbors beneath us reported me (they thought I was practicing on a real kit).  I was advised to try using tennis balls on the legs of the pad set.  I decided not to take the chance, but to get to a studio more often.  While a good electronic kit is not cheap, it is going to be the cheapest solution where you will be able to continue to play in your apartment, and not disturb your neighbors.

Comment: You can still hear the practise/electro kick through the floor. I gave up eventually & only ever play in a practise studio.

Comment: From my experience, electronic set does help a bit, but won't solve the problem. Especially when using double kicks.

Comment: I think you could try cork tiles. It has a very good sound and vibration insulator here is a Quote from Wikipedia under passive insulation. "Pads or sheets of flexible materials such as elastomers, rubber, cork, dense foam and laminate materials.Elastomer pads, dense closed cell foams and laminate materials are often used under heavy machinery, under common household items, in vehicles and even under higher performing audio systems". An other advantage it's not so expensive, and don't have to build.

Comment: I hate playing electronic drums and you really can't learn drumming on them. The only drummer I know who has seriously used an electronic kit for practice for more than a little while is also one of the worst drummers I know. He has timing down but no sense of touch.

Comment: @ToddWilcox - I use a set in my studio, but agree with you that there are many nuances in play that work so much better using a real kit. But it's better than nothing - if I want to play at any time, no-one gets disturbed.

Comment: Mesh heads and low volume cymbals are another option. The LV cymbals really feel and sound and respond like real cymbals. The mesh heads are just ok, but miles better than even the mesh headed V-drums. Something about the triggers doesn't really do positional sensing well enough, but hitting off the sweet spot on a mesh head on a real drum sounds much worse than hitting on the sweet spot of..

Comment: @ToddWilcox - trouble is, then, you need another kit to gig with - and store between gigs. Yet another reason I tend to stick with bass or keys - but even keys mean I have to have separate 'boards in preference to stripping the studio. But by now, we're off the subject somewhat !

Comment: But... you wouldn’t gig with the electronic kit, right? Either way you’re signed up for two kits.

Comment: @ToddWilcox - true, I must agree. Although the electronic kit takes up *slightly* less room in the studio.

Comment: These are used professionally in studios and live: https://www.roland.com/us/products/td-50k/ - They've gotten the cymbals figured out. Anything less than the TD-30 is giving up a lot I'd agree.

Answer (score 0):

I just bought a sweet 4 X 6 rubber mat thats 3/8 thick. It only cost $85. Wood frame building so I hear everything above me. It sucks being a drummer trying to be quiet, it just goes against everything we do. Oh nelly! If it doesn't work then at least I have a heavy duty mat for weightlifting or maybe use it when I buy a house for the basement.